# How to extract piece with '\' and spacec?

Tags: regex, python-2.7

> "This is a piece of 432432\5321 text".

Numbers could be whatever long and also could be letters. How to get only **432432\5321** part of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample:

```
(\d+\\\d+)
```

Group of digits followed by slash and followed by group of digits. Surrounding parenthesis is a capturing group.

Here is the fiddle: https://regex101.com/r/gI5rG4/2

**EDIT:**

I have missed that you also want letters. Then use `\w` instead of `\d`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `\w` for matching alphanumeric characters and `\\`for matching the backslash:

```
(\w+\\\w+)
```

This would match inputs like `32432\5321` as well those with letters in it, e.g. `32A1\BB1`

Fiddle: https://regex101.com/r/yF2aX1/2

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following example:

```
input = 'This is a piece of 432432\\5321 text'
print re.findall(r'(\d+(?:\\\d+)+)', input)
```

It can handle both input like `111\222`, `111\222\333`, etc.